# JavaScript(node.js) storing(var) information from .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, riot-games-api

I'm using a a js lib called teemojs to get information from riot API using node.js and want to store what i get in a var to call back to later, this code

```
api.get('euw1', 'summoner.getBySummonerName', playerName)
    .then(data => console.log(data.id))
```

gives me what I want but I'm not able to store it in a var to access globally 
any ideas on what i can do

P.S I'm trying to say something like this

```
api.get('euw1', 'summoner.getBySummonerName', playerName)
    .then(data => var Result = (data.id))
```

Comment: The results of an asynchronous operation needs to be used INSIDE the `.then()` handler or in a function you call from there.  The timing of the async completion is completely unknown so the only place you know when it's safe to use the value is inside the `.then()` handler.  That's how async development works in node.js.  You can store stuff into a global context, but you will have a hard time knowing when it's safe to use it from there.

Comment: Can you link me a example on how to use async/await?

Comment: The question yours has been marked a duplicate of has numerous examples in it.  There are also hundreds of articles and tutorials on the web on the subject which you can find as easily as I.  It is a well publicized and written about new feature of Javascript.

Comment: Can I just say that this wrapper being called "teemojs" makes me happy inside? That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a variable before your promise like

```
var myVar;
api.get('euw1', 'summoner.getBySummonerName', playerName)
    .then(data => {
       myVar = data.id;
       console.log(myVar); // myVar is defined
    })
console.log(myVar); // myVar is undefined
```

You can also use async/await like

```
ty {
  const {id} = await api.get('euw1', 'summoner.getBySummonerName', playerName);
  console.log(id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, if i call console.log(myVar) comes back "undefined"

Comment: Did you console log in the `then` or outside ? 'Cause outside the promise is not resolved.

Comment: I'm trying to do it outside but I've never used promises

Comment: Take a look at y edit. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Comment: So i cant get the "data.id" outside of the promise?

Comment: Yes, with a new promise, but it will be the same though. You will have to wrap your logic in a new promise if you want `myVar` defined.

Comment: I've added the code you gave me and it works but I still dont see how I can make myVar global? do i need for everything to be in the brackets of the try?

Comment: That's it. You have to wrap your logic where you need `myVar` once the promise is resolved. As wrote @jfriend00 `The results of an asynchronous operation needs to be used INSIDE the .then() handler or in a function you call from there.`

Comment: I think you confused poor Luke by showing the correct and incorrect console.log (he probably did both).